# How to replace a particular value in a Pyspark Dataframe column with another value?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have the following Pyspark Dataframe called 'df':

```
A = ["OTH/CON", "Freight Collect", "OTH/CON", "DBG"]
B = [2, 3, 4, 5]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(A, B), schema=['A', 'B'])
```

In the column 'A', I need to replace the values "OTH/CON" & "Freight Collect" with another string "Collect". And replace "DBG" by "Dispose". Then place the values into a new column 'aa'. I do the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("aa", F.when(F.col("A").isin(["OTH/CON"]), F.lit("Collect")).otherwise(F.col("A")))
df = df.withColumn("aa", F.when(F.col("A").isin(["Freight Collect"]), F.lit("Collect")).otherwise(F.col("A")))
df = df.withColumn("aa", F.when(F.col("A").isin(["DBG"]), F.lit("Dispose")).otherwise(F.col("A")))
```

But I end up getting only "Freight Collect" value changed to "Collect". "OTH/CON" remains as it is.

I'm not able to figure out why!

My expected output is as follows:

```
+---------------+---+-------+
|              A|  B|     aa|
+---------------+---+-------+
|        OTH/CON|  2|Collect|
|Freight Collect|  3|Collect|
|        OTH/CON|  4|Collect|
|            DBG|  5|Dispose|
+---------------+---+-------+
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge multiple `isin` conditions into one

```
(df
    .withColumn('aa', F
        .when(F.col('A').isin(['OTH/CON', 'Freight Collect']), F.lit('Collect'))
        .when(F.col('A').isin(['DBG']), F.lit('Dispose'))
        .otherwise(F.col('A'))
    )
    .show()
)

+---------------+---+-------+
|              A|  B|     aa|
+---------------+---+-------+
|        OTH/CON|  2|Collect|
|Freight Collect|  3|Collect|
|        OTH/CON|  4|Collect|
|            DBG|  5|Dispose|
+---------------+---+-------+
```

Comment: No, I'm clear with my logic. I intend to not tamper with the original columns at all, hence want to update the values of column 'A' into a new column 'aa'. But when I do so, I end up getting only "Freight Collect" value changed to "Collect".

Comment: can you post the exact your expected output in your question? I will update my answer then

Comment: I've updated my expected output in the question.

Comment: and I've updated my answer :)

Comment: hm no, not really. If I were you, I'd test with some subsets of the data and narrow down to see which records/columns cause the issue

Comment: Ok, that was apparently due to interchanging the position of the [] & () brackets. It executed fine after correcting it. But it's still resulting only in one of the values present in the column being changed. The rest is somehow still remaining unchanged. Though your solution has worked perfectly fine for the smaller example I've given, it's somehow not working for my actual bigger dataframe. What could possibly be the reason?

Comment: it might be the text is not exact `'OTH/CON'` or `'Freight Collect'`, i.e it could have some extra space. Again, I'd recommend to narrow down to see which records are updated incorrectly, and figure out why

Comment: Also FYI, I'm assigning the complete line back to df. As in df = df.withcolumn(...)

Comment: I did verify if the text is exact. But still the same issue. What I notice is that, even if I merge multiple conditions into one like your solution, but if there are two instances in the same column, then it fails. This is not working for this example as well. I've updated my question to incorporate this. Can you please try and check with this one? I've added a replacement text for "DBG" as well as the requirement.

Comment: hm, `DBG` to  `Dispose` is easy (updated answer), but what do you mean by "two instances in the same column"?

Comment: By "two instances" I meant, having two string replacements for the same column - which is "Collect" and "Dispose". It wasn't working when I split the code and wrote it in 3 separate lines (as shown in my question), but the concise solution you provided is working fine. It's working fine for my actual dataframe as well! Marking it as the solution to my issue. But what could be the reason for this? Even in the split form, it seem technically correct right?

Comment: Now I see what you were saying from the beginning. Here is the reason, think about your 3 separate lines as: 1) you create new `aa` column with values replaced for `OTH/CON`. 2) you **override** `aa` column with new values that are replaced for 'Freight Collect', means all the calculated values at 1) had been gone. Same as 3)